# live stream mosaic to twitch using nginx and ffmpeg

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg

I've been trying to make a mosaic of two rtmp streams and resend it to Twitch, i´m using a nginx with a rtmp module and ffmpeg. I've come out with this but doesnt work:

```
exec /usr/bin/ffmpeg - report -i rtmp://localhost/app/input -i rtmp://localhost/app/input -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=480:-1,setsar=1[l];[1:v]scale=480:-1,setsar=1[r];[l][r]hstack;[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map v -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://live-mia.twitch.tv/app/xxxxxxxxxx
```

The  report shows an  endless loop

cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)

how do I get this stream working?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Show the full output.

Comment: sorry, There is nothing shown on twitch, but the input signal is recived by the server. i can't find ffmpeg log file

Comment: Add the `-report` option to generate an excessively verbose log file in the current directory if you can't refer to the console output.

Comment: Thanks @LordNeckbeard. Its took me a while but i've been able figure out that the -map "[v]" was wrong, it must be instead : -map v
but i get another error :
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
someone have any idea?

Comment: @JorgeVértiz I missed that when I looked the first time. The problem is the lack of a labeled output for the video from the filtering. You can keep `-map "[v]"`, but change `[l][r]hstack;` to `[l][r]hstack[v];`. Since you mostly figured that out you can add that as the answer. As for the other issues you should ask one question per post and new questions should be new posts.

Answer (score 0):

At last, this the code I' been able to make work

```
exec /usr/bin/ffmpeg - report -i rtmp://localhost/app/input -i rtmp://localhost/app/input2 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=480:-1,setsar=1[l];[1:v]scale=480:-1,setsar=1[r];[l][r]hstack[v];[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -ac 2 -f flv rtmp://live-mia.twitch.tv/app/xxxxxxxxxx
```

It must be re-encoded the stream in order to Twitch been able to shown it. Also , as im runing ffmpeg in a nginx, the nginx's user must have root permissions.